# How to fix "Unable to validate the following destination configurations" in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I am writing a CloudFormation that creates an S3 bucket and an SQS queue. In the same CFN, I am trying to allow the S3 bucket to send messages to the SQS queue. I keep getting this error:

> Unable to validate the following destination configurations

I spent about 12 hours in trial and error yesterday. I think I have now read every article out there about this topic. Most seem to be on Lambdas or SNS Topics, but the process should be the same. I have tried adding a DependsOn in the S3 bucket so that the SQS policy gets created before the bucket, but that didn't work. I then did the other solution suggested which was to create the bucket and sqs, then create the policy for the sqs bucket that allows the s3 to publish to it, and finally create the notification. I was successful up to creating the notification.

Here is my sqs creation:

```
SQSBiaData:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Ref Queue
      Tags:
        - Key: 'Environment'
          Value: !Ref Environment
```

Here is my sqs policy:

```
SQSBiaPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      Queues:
        - !Ref SQSBiaData
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Sid: SendMessage
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              AWS: !Ref AccountNumber
            Action: SQS:SendMessage
            Resource:
              - 'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456:bia-data'
            Condition:
              ArnLike:
                aws:SourceArn: 
                  Fn::Join:
                  - ''
                  - - 'arn:aws:s3:*:*:'
                    - 'bia-data'
```

Here is my bucket creation:

```
 S3BucketBiaData:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DependsOn: 
      - SQSBiaPolicy
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      BucketEncryption:
           ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
            - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
                 SSEAlgorithm: AES256
      Tags:
        - Key: 'Environment'
          Value: !Ref Environment
      NotificationConfiguration:
        QueueConfigurations:
          - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
            Queue: 'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456:bia-data'
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                  - Name: 'prefix'
                    Value: 'manifest/'
```

Finally, here is my bucket policy:

```
S3BucketBiaPolicies:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties:
        Bucket: !Ref BucketName
        PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Sid: DenyInsecureConnections
                Effect: Deny
                Principal: '*'
                Action: s3:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3BucketBiaData}/*'
                Condition:
                  Bool:
                    aws:SecureTransport: 'false'
              - Sid: DenyPublicReadGrant
                Effect: Deny
                Principal:
                  AWS: "*"
                Action:
                - s3:PutObject
                - s3:PutObjectAcl
                Resource:
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3BucketBiaData}/*'
                Condition:
                  StringLike:
                    s3:x-amz-grant-read:
                    - "*http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers*"
                    - "*http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers*"
              - Sid: OnlyAllowVPCAccess
                Effect: Deny
                Principal: '*'
                Action: s3:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3BucketBiaData}/*'
                Condition:
                  ForAnyValue:StringNotEquals:
                    'aws: sourceVpce': !Ref VPCs
```

I am expecting the CFN to happen in this order:

1. SQS
2. SQS Policy
3. S3 Bucket
4. S3 Bucket Policy

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Keep in mind that the CFN works UNTIL I add the NotificationConfiguration section.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know the exact issue of your problem, I'd like to suggest heavier usage of Pseudo params to make debugging easier.

I would replace the "us-east-1"s with `${AWS::Region}` and "123456"s with `${AWS::AccountId}`.

I would also use a !GetAtt when referencing the Queue in the S3 definition. Instead of `Queue: 'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456:bia-data'
Queue: !GetAtt SQSBiaData.Arn`

Finally, I would use the parameter "BucketName" as a Ref in the last line of your SQS policy.

These changes might make debugging easier for someone on here.